# NoReverseMatch for the new object

Tags: python, django

Use Django 1.10.4. I have a model Stream, for which I created CreateView. When objects are created through the admin panel everything works fine, but when I use the form CreateView, an object is created (either in admin or in the database is no different from the other), but attempts to provide a link to it through DetailView result in an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /  
Reverse for 'detail_stream' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 17}' not found. 
2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', 'streams/(?P<pk>[0-9])/$']
```

This error occurs when displaying the ListView, and then only for an object created through CreateView.
The place where the error occurs:

```
{% for item in stream_list %}
    <a href="/streams{% url "detail_stream" pk=item.id %}">
    ...
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

When you try to go directly to DetailView (http://127.0.0.1:8000/streams/17) 404 error.
urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url    
from .views import StreamDetail, StreamUpdate

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', StreamList.as_view(), name='streams'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/update/$', StreamUpdate.as_view()),
]
```

Also, the url for the streams added to the main site urlpatterns.

View:

```
class StreamCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
        newtags = []
        for tag in form.cleaned_data['tags']:
            tag = regex.sub('',tag)
            newtags.append(tag)
        form.cleaned_data['tags'] = newtags
        return super(StreamCreate,self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        return super(StreamCreate,self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('streams')
```

I suspect that something I did not realize at CreateView, but I can not understand that and need your help.

Comment: I removed some detail from your question that didn't appear to have anything to do with the issue. if theres anything you believe was required, please feel free to add it back in

Comment: As well as fixing the regexes in @yedpodtrzitko's answer, you should change the link in your template to `<a href="{% url 'detail_stream' pk=item.id %}">`. You don't need the `/streams` prefix when using the url tag.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you but I think I need it because I have this view in main urlpatterns, for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/ is the same http://127.0.0.1:8000/streams/1/ , but I want users to go to /streams

Comment: That's very unusual. I would avoid having the same content at `/1/` and `/streams/1/` if possible. Even if you do want to do that, you should be able to use different names or namespaces so that you don't have to hardcode the `/streams` prefix.

Comment: @Alasdair so thanks for reminding me this, it needs to be refactored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex in the given route is wrong.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream')
```

`[0-9]` means it expects a single-digit number. 17 has two digits, so the regexp needs to take that into account (add `+` there)

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream')
```

Some other routes in there have the same issue.